# how to load a hyperlink ontop of an image

Tags: javascript, css, html, styles

creating a basic HTML page, should show a logo as the banner, with a hyperlink on the bottom right of the logo.
Then an iframe as the page.
Storing the image and the iframe inside 2 seperate divs, then put that inside a div.

Problem is when I try to add the time, it loads it below the image, and the iframe sits ontop of that blocking it out. Have tried Z Index and messing about with divs...any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Interactive Map - Meath Field Names Project</title>
    <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}

    html, body 
    {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        overflow:hidden; 
        background-color:#E0DEDF;
    }

    iframe 
    {
        height:100%;
        width:100%
    }

    .content 
    {
        width: 100%;
        height:90%
    }

    .logoheader
   {        

        width: 100%;
        height: 10%;    
   }

   .fullPage
    {
        height:100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .hlink
    {
        z-index: 1;
        color:#ACD0D4; 
        font-size:26px; 
        font-family:verdana
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="fullPage">
       <div class="logoheader">
        <img src="images/banner.png" alt="IMAGES" width="100%" />
        <a class="hlink" href="http://www.google.com/">Help Page</a> 
       </div>

       <div class="content">
            <iframe class="wrapper"//linktoIFrame</iframe>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To use `z-index` you need to use `position` aswell.

Comment: @-1 thank you for your input, everyone is entitled to their own opinion but the Lion doesn't care for the opinion of sheep....NOTE..Would have been just as quick to explain position instead of negativity but meeeehhhhh some people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two solutions seem to work:

- Negative margin-top with float right on the link
- Adding a wrapper with position relative and absolutely positioning the link;

```css
a.hlink {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    float: right;
    z-index: 5;
}

#wrapper {
    position; relative;   
}

#wrapper .otherlink{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3px;
    right: 3px;    
}
```

```html
<img src="images/banner.png" alt="IMAGES" width="100%" height="75" />
<a class="hlink" href="http://www.google.com/">Help Page</a> 

<p>more content</p><hr/>

<div id="wrapper" style="position:relative">
  <img src="images/banner.png" alt="IMAGES"  width="100%" height="75" /> 
  <a class="hlink" href="http://www.google.com/">Help Page</a>   
</div>
```

Comment: yeah I was missing the position when I added z-index, thanks for the help